# Azure Storage Account Data Replication Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am new to Azure, and one question bothers me. I have 2 storage accounts in different regions (West Europe and East US). The West Europe one  is the "general" one (Read/Write) and the other one is the seccondary one (only Read option). When the user adds a new item, it will be added to the general storage account, and after some time (let's say 1 minute), all the newly added data will be "pushed" to the secondary storage account. I want to achieve this via a custom implementation.

So my question is: how (if possible) can I achieve this? I mean i can seperetly sync them, tables, files, blobs etc. But is it possible to achieve this in a more generic way?

By "generic," I mean that the function will receive a string or collection of strings ("Table"), and with that string, it will sync only these services. If the string is "all," it should sync all the types.

The idea is to have one storage account for Write/Read located in the main region and several other accounts for Read, located in other legions. So when the user from region A (let's say East US) wants to read the items (let's say domains), his request will be redirected to the nearest secondary location. When a user creates a new domain, his request is routed to the main region Storage Account (Write/Read). And after some time, all the storage accounts must be synced, so the user can see the changes. I don't think Azure Storage redundancy is the right approach for that.

Thank you!

Comment: So, you are looking for some code or approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Storage client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design?source=recommendations) to perform read and update requests against the primary region endpoint.

References taken from [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy) and [MSDoc2.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/common/geo-redundant-design-legacy.md)

If the primary region is unavailable, you can automatically redirect read requests to the secondary region.

```
string accountName = "storageaccount";
            Uri primaryAccountUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/");
            Uri secondaryAccountUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/");

              BlobClientOptions blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions()
              {
                    Retry = {
                    Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),

                    MaxRetries = 5,

                    Mode = RetryMode.Exponential,
                    MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                },

               GeoRedundantSecondaryUri = secondaryAccountUri
            };

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(primaryAccountUri, new DefaultAzureCredential(), blobClientOptions);
```

Read request retries from the primary region are redirected to the secondary region.

[image]

[image]

You can also achieve this by using Azure Traffic Manager, allows you to distribute incoming traffic across multiple endpoints in different regions.

And configure Traffic Manager to route traffic to the nearest endpoint based on the location.

> You can have a primary storage account in the main region for write/read operations and several secondary storage accounts in other regions for read-only operations.

When you create a new domain, the request is routed to the primary storage account in the main region.

You can use a custom implementation to periodically sync the data between the primary and secondary storage accounts.

> To synchronize data between different regions in Azure Blob Storage, you can use the Azure Storage Data Movement library, AzCopy, Azure Data Factory, Blobfuse, or Azure Import/Export service.